# How to debug Yarn lint failed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

Team
I am running below Jenkins pipeline to do yarn lint and it works on retries but at times gives me error. Any hint how can I debug what is problem in failure case? Is there a debug option with yarn lint?

```
parallel {
        stage('Lint') {
          steps {
            container('ui') {
              script {
                def cmd = "yarn lint:ci"
                def log = "logs/yarn_lint-ci.txt"
                sendSlackUpdate("lint", STATUSES.RUNNING)
                lintSucceeded = logCallReturnStatus(
                  cmd,
                  log,
                  true,
                )
```

Output is just this

```
07:25:05  Archiving artifacts
07:25:05  Recording fingerprints
07:25:05  [Pipeline] echo
07:25:05  yarn lint:ci FAILED
07:25:05  [Pipeline] unstable
07:25:05  WARNING: yarn lint:ci FAILED
07:25:05  [Pipeline] updateGitlabCommitStatus
07:25:05  [Pipeline] slackSend
```